# CloudWatch Events Rule not finding EC2 targets using tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, ssm, amazon-systems-manager, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I have a `CloudWatch Event Rule` that will trigger an `SSM Run Command Document`. The targets will be identified using tags. My resources are defined according to the following *CloudFormation* template:

```
SSMRunCommandDocument:
  Type: AWS::SSM::Document
  Properties:
    DocumentType: 'Command'
    Content:
      schemaVersion: '2.2'
      description: "Some description"
      mainSteps:
        - action: "aws:runShellScript"
          name: runShellScript
          inputs:
            runCommand:
              - !Sub |
                  #!/bin/bash -e
                  echo "Hello StackOverflow!" > test.log
    Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: EC2Name
      - Key: Environment
        Value: DEV
CloudWatchEventRule:
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties:
    Description: "The ARN from the eventbridge role resource"
    EventPattern: 
      source:
        - "aws.autoscaling"
      detail-type:
        - "EC2 Instance-terminate Lifecycle Action"
      detail:
        AutoScalingGroupName:
          - !Ref 'MyAutoScalingGroup'
    State: "ENABLED"
    Targets:
      - Id: "Some target ID."
        Arn: !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:document/${SSMRunCommandDocument}"
        RoleArn: "The ARN from the eventbridge role resource"
        RunCommandParameters:
          RunCommandTargets:
            - Key: "tag: Name"
              Values:
                - EC2Name
            - Key: "tag: Environment"
              Values:
                - DEV
```

And I have the following role, from which the `ARN` is used in the *CloudFormation* template above:

```
AutoScalingLifecycleHookEventRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Sid: ''
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - events.amazonaws.com
          Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
    Description: "The role that will be used by AWS EventBridge to start an SSM Run Command document."
AutoScalingLifecycleHookEventManagedPolicy:
  Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Action:
            - 'ssm:StartAutomationExecution'
          Resource:
            - "arn:*:ssm:*:*:automation-definition/AWS-RunShellScript*"
          Effect: Allow
        - Action:
            - "iam:PassRole"
          Resource:
            - "arn:*:ssm:*:*:role/*"
          Effect: Allow
        - Action:
            - 'ssm:*'
          Resource:
            - "arn:*:ssm:*:*:*"
          Effect: Allow
        - Action:
            - "ssm:SendCommand"
          Resource:
            - !Sub "arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:instance/*"
            - !Sub "arn:aws:ssm:${AWS::Region}:*:document/*"
          Effect: Allow
    Roles:
      - !Ref AutoScalingLifecycleHookEventRole
```

Manually, I can trigger a `RunCommand` using the same tags that are specified in the *CloudFormation* template just fine. But when the `RunCommand` is triggered by an `Event Rule`, the history on the `RunCommand` page tells us that no targets were found this time:

[image]

What permissions or configurations am I missing?

Comment: Just wanted to say, thank you for sharing your example, it helped me get through some annoying issues today!

Comment: @furydrive you're very welcome, I'm happy that I was able to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that a space in the `tag: tag-key` field should not be there:

```
RunCommandParameters:
  RunCommandTargets:
    - Key: "tag:Name"
      Values:
        - EC2Name
    - Key: "tag:Environment"
      Values:
        - DEV
```